# failed to open stream: Permission denied on magento

Tags: magento-1.8, permissions, file-permissions

I want to add a new module for export attributes in magento, so this is the [module](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/import-export-product-attributes-by-magerips.html).

When I upload this module, I have this error in my `system.log` and I don't understand why it speaks to me of permissions because I already downloaded other modules without problem.

Can you help me thank.

This is my errors :

```
2017-07-29T09:51:13+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(C:\wamp\www\magento\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\importexportattributes\adminimportexportattributes.phtml): failed to open stream: Permission denied  in C:\wamp\www\easybuy\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php on line 241

2017-07-29T09:51:13+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'C:\wamp\www\magento\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\importexportattributes\adminimportexportattributes.phtml' for inclusion (include_path='C:\wamp\www\easybuy\app\code\local;C:\wamp\www\easybuy\app\code\community;C:\wamp\www\easybuy\app\code\core;C:\wamp\www\easybuy\lib;.;C:\php\pear')  in C:\wamp\www\easybuy\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php on line 241
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are loading from two separate app roots, `C:\wamp\www\magento` and `C:\wamp\www\easybuy`.

Run the following on your DB and make sure all of your urls are correct:

`select * from core_config_data where path like '%base_url%';`

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have some permission restriction in your folder, try these commands:

Magento File permissions:

1. `chmod -R 644 ./*`
2. `find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;`
3. `find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;`
4. `chmod 550 ./mage`

For more informations, [Magento guides](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installer-privileges_after.html).

Comment: Good answer for question